# No password required after Power Nap

Tags: sleep-wake, password, power-nap

I have enabled the setting *Require password 1 minute after sleep or screen saver begins*. However, I sometimes noticed that my password is not asked after I open my laptop in the morning. This seems to coincide with Power Nap runs: if you open the laptop during that period, or probably in the minute after it goes back to sleep (checked using the Console: `RTC: Maintenance`), the password is not asked.

Is this a bug/feature, or is there another setting I'm missing? Can others confirm this? [(There is a simple test to find out when your computer is in Power Nap.)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/how-to-determine-when-a-mac-is-in-power-nap-state)

Answer (score 1):

I tried asking a similar question on the Apple discussion forum but wasn't allowed. It seems to be a bug. If you log out and log in the settings work as they should, at least they did in my case.
I could put my MBP (2010, running Yosemite) to sleep via the menu, close the lid or simply let it go to screen saver and then sleep, let it stand over night and still not be asked for my password, so I don't think its only a Power Nap issue.

Comment: It seems to me like you've your Automatic Login turned on under `Users & Groups`..

Comment: Nope, not that.